# The maximum row size for the used table type spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Hello i m using spring boot i need to create my entity at mysql server but i reselve error :

** Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs**

what i should to do to create my data base please  !

classe is :

```
@Entity
public class rfpobject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
private int ide;
private String unit;
private String rfpid;
private String requestid;
private String incoming;
private String projecttitle;
private String serviceline;
private String businessunit;
private String requsitionbusinessunit;
private String country;
private String targetpropose;
private int rfx;
private String workflowtracking;
private String protocol;
private String jourfixkunde;
private String rejectedstatus;
private String closedreason;
private String practice;
private String startdate;
private String enddate;
private String vertragsart;
private String rfpcomment;
private double persondays;
private String accountexecutive;
private String accountsalesmanager;
private String expertsales;
private String deliveryunit;
private String deliveryresponsible;
private String requisitioner;
private String procurement;
private String referencenumber;
private int atoscontractno;
private String candidates;
private String itec;
private String tcv;
private String updated;
private String updatedby;
private String portfolio;
private String path;
private String rmprotocol;
private int rm;
private String wfm_id;
private String needconfopart;
private String confirmationofparticipation;
private String propose;
private String lastcall;
private String lastcalldate;
private String skills;
private String leistungserbringung;
private String rollefunktion;
private String inhaltscope;
private String laufzeitperspektive;
private String laufzeitangefragt;
private String phase;
private String fristverlaengerung;
private String closedstatus;
private String deferred_till;
private int sipa_yn;
private String po_no;
private int nessie_no;
private String number_of_persons;
private String att_job_site;
private String att_language;
private String att_main_topics;
private String ref_rfpid;
private String ref_history;
private String ref_rejections;
private String rv_rej_status_details;
private String rv_alliance_manager;
private String rv_final_status;
private String rv_cust_list_date;
private String rv_final_note;
private String rv_atos_root_causes;
private String currency;
private String externalid;
private String resultstatus;
private String reasoncode;
private String sysid;
private String ncrm_comment;
private String idemand_comment;
private String offshore_comment;
private String rv_rc_updby;
private String rv_rc_date;
private String rv_finalcomment;
private String rv_finaldate;
private double tcv_euro;
private int rem_active;
private int rem_send;
private int remcop_active;
private int remcop_send;
private String idemand;
private String idemand_url;
private int labour_leasing_yn;
private String cas_no;
private String prolongation;
private String rv_skills_miss_1;
private String rv_skills_miss_2;
private String rv_skills_miss_3;
private String ref_renewal_date;
```

so when i excute i get error Row Size Too large
application propreties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atos1?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every String will be produced a `VARCHAR(255)` column.

And you have many of them. This causes the error.

You have two options:

1) Define the Column size

```
@Column(length = 20)
private String unit;
```

or

```
@Column(columnDefinition= "VARCHAR(20)")
private String unit;
```

2) Don't let Hibernate create the tables and write the DDL yourself.